# Dynamically allocated string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, malloc

I have defined a struct that stores the length and content of a string.

```
struct sir {
    int length;
    char* string;
};
```

I am trying to dynamically alocate memory space for this string using:

```
s->string = malloc(sizeof(char) * (s->length));
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
```

Can you please guide in finishing this function?

PS: I would really like to know how write values from keyboard in this newly created string?
    Tnx in advance!

Comment: Replace it with `std::string`. No manual memory management needed. If you must do it yourself, use `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: `c` or `c++`? Why use `malloc` in `c++`?

Comment: And also please see this post: [do i cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I managed to write the values from keyboard by myself. So nevemind the   last question. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) will return `void *`, which needs to be converted to `char *` explicitly in `C++` (though not needed in `C`).

Try

```
s->string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (s->length));
```

---

**Edit:** As you're using `C++`, as @chris commented, you should consider to use `std::string` instead. No manual memory management is needed. If you must do it yourself, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Yes. it works now. One last think: how can i write values in this string?

Comment: I think, you should add an explanation as to why `s->string = malloc(sizeof(char) * (s->length));` is actually seen in so much code, and why it won't compile for the OP.

Comment: @user3423372 You can use [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling the program as a C++ program. The return type of function `malloc` is `void *` However a pointer to void may not be implicitly converted to a pointer to other type in C++ and the error message says about this clear enough.

So write

```
s->string = ( char * )malloc(sizeof(char) * (s->length));.
```

However the coorect way is to use operator new instead of malloc in C++

```
s->string = new char[s->length];.
```

Again if it is a C++ program then instead of the structure it would be better to use a class with explicitly defined constructors, destructor and the copy bassignment operator.

Or compile your program as a C program if you indeed want to deal with a C program.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow forget "new"?

Comment: I know. but i got the idea :)